# Seforim Hakedoshim on the Third Beis HaMikdosh

Tags: sources-mekorot, beis-hamikdash, messianic-redemption

Rav Tzvi Meyer Zilberberg 
quoted from Seforim Hakedoshim, the following:
*"As soon as the Second Beis Hamikdash was destroyed, 
Hashem began preparing the final Geulah and the Third Beis HaMikdash."*

Does anyone know which sefer actually says this?

Comment: how do you know he said this? Did you hear him live? Was this quoted in a secondary source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this article](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/52753/jewish/The-Legalities-of-Destruction.htm), and especially this quote from the Talmud Yerushalmi:

> On the day that the Holy Temple was destroyed, a Jew was plowing his field when his cow suddenly called out. An Arab was passing by and heard the low of the cow. Said the Arab to the Jew: "Son of Judah! Unyoke your cow, free the stake of your plow, for your Holy Temple has now been destroyed."
>
> The cow then lowed a second time. Said the Arab to the Jew: "Son of Judah! Yoke your cow, reset the stake of your plow, for the Redeemer has now been born..."
>
> Said Rabbi Bon: "Do we need to learn this from an Arab? The Torah itself says so. The verse (Isaiah 10:34) predicts, "And the cedar of Lebanon shall be felled by the mighty one." And what is written in the very next verse? "There shall come forth a shoot out of the stem of Yishai"
>
> **(Jerusalem Talmud, Berachot 2:4)**

Comment: It is not clear for me, can you explain a little more the allusion to the third temple?

Comment: @kouty: As soon as the Beit Hamikdash was destroyed G-d was already preparing for Moshiach, who will build the 3rd Beit Hamikdash (incidentally, the Lubavitcher Rebbe points out that this means that G-d was already preparing before the destruction, since the baby was conceived 9 months prior). ---- There are sources that talk about the Beit Hamikdash being built in Heaven through our Mitzvot (or tears, see here: http://matzav.com/avraham-fried-explains-source-of-lyrics/ ) throught the exile, so that it will be ready to descend from Heaven when Moshiach comes.

Comment: Gemara in Succa... OK I see.